# Custom sorting categories on Home Page in Woocommerce 3 Storefront theme

Tags: php, wordpress, sorting, woocommerce, custom-taxonomy

[image]
I show a list of categories on the main page. I need the last category to be second. I studied the sorting options, but they are not suitable.
By name, by ID, randomly. **Сategory with id "50" need to be second on the list.**

```
add_filter( 'storefront_product_categories_args', 'custom_storefront_product_categories');
function custom_storefront_product_categories( $args ) {
    $args['limit'] = 9;
    $args['columns'] = 3;
    $args['orderby'] = 'id'; // sort by id category
    return $args;
}
```

---

EDIT:

I have tried to add the product categories sorted IDs using:

```
function custom_storefront_category_filtering( $args ) {
    $args['ids'] = '16,50,17,18,19,20,21,22,23'; // need such a sequence of categories
    return $args;
}
add_filter('storefront_product_categories_shortcode_args','custom_storefront_category_filtering' );
```

But it only include the product categories.

Comment: Can you rephrase your question? How would you like to reorder categories on homepage on your Storefront theme based website? What is `ids`?

Comment: @KashifRafique, I want to add a custom sort order. Standard do not allow sorting in the right order

Answer (score 1):

As product categories are a custom taxonomy `id`, `ids` or even `ID` will not work. Instead you will use **`term_id`** which is the appropriated argument value for **`orderby`** argument in this context.

> **Why?** because we don't target post IDs **but terms IDs**.

So in your filter hook:

```
add_filter( 'storefront_product_categories_args', 'custom_storefront_product_categories');
function custom_storefront_product_categories( $args ) {
    $args['limit'] = 9;
    $args['columns'] = 3;
    $args['orderby'] = 'term_id';

    return $args;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). Tested and works.

Comment: Hi! I updated the question a little, maybe it became a little clearer. This answer unfortunately does not fit.

Comment: The answer answers your initial question… If you want to sort your product categories from their Ids you need to use `$args['orderby'] = 'term_id';`… You can't sort them in a custom order like you try to do. Now you could use `$args['orderby'] = 'term_order';` to sort them in the "menu order" like in the backend where you can sort them in a custom order…

Comment: Thank you for unswer, but I think you misunderstand the question. I'm trying to build categories in their own order.

Comment: $args['orderby'] = 'term_id'; - the same $args['orderby'] = 'id';